# Javascript XML error alert

Tags: javascript, xml

I have XML stored in the variable 'ad' and 'addd':
Variable ad:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<name>
<data>
<Id>003</Id>
 </data>
<data>
<Id>006</Id>
</data>
 ....
</name>
```

And Variable addd:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<name>
<data>
<Id>009</Id>
</data>
<data>
<Id>005</Id>
</data>
...
</name>
```

I have written a `ttt` function:

```
function ttt(ad,addd) {
var match = ad.match(/<Id\/>/);
var matcht = addd.match(/<Id\/>/);
if ((! match || match.length == 0) && (! matcht || matcht.length == 0)){
    return "Below is the details of the Id of ad:\n\n" + ad.split("<Id>")[1].split("</Id>")[0]; + "\n\n And, Below is the details of the Id of addd:\n\n" +addd.split("<Id>")[1].split("</Id>")[0];
}
```

}

I need `If` `Id` is not blank from ad variable then return alert as `error` with `Id` as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<name>
<data>
<Id>003</Id>
</data>
<data>
<Id>006</Id>
</data>
</name>
```

And, I need `If` `Id` is not blank from addd variable then return alert as `error` with `Id` as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<name>
<data>
<Id>009</Id>
</data>
<data>
<Id>005</Id>
</data>
</name>
```

Comment: `If Id is not blank` can you define what you meant by `id` not being blank?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need If Id is not blank then return alert as error with Id otherwise
>   i dont need alert.

If by ***id not blank*** you mean that ad doesn't have `<Id/>`, then simply try

```
var match = ad.match(/<ID\/>/);
if( !match || match.length == 0 )
{
  return ad.split("<Id>")[1].split( "</Id>" )[0];
}
```

Comment: i tried this code bot not working, my question was If Id not blank then i need <name>
<data>
<Id/>
</data>
</name>  otherwise i dont need any alert

Comment: `i tried this code bot not working` what output do you get? Also what do you mean by `if id not blank`?

Comment: If Id element have some value like 123 in xml then i need data in alert return as it is <name>
  <data>
    <Id>123</Id>
  </data>
</name>

otherwise i dont need any alert return

Comment: i need XML data in return if condition true not particular value. that provided code by you is working to get Id value but i need whole xml